# Python DataFrame Add new columns

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm reading a data frame into panda's from a CSV file - from there I'm doing a split on two of the columns to get series data (non-expanded)

```
df = pd.read_csv('fromTableau.csv')
for systemA, systemB in df.groupby('my._id'):
    systemA = df['systemA'].str.split('|')
    systemB = df['systemB'].str.split('|')
```

how do I replace systemA and systemB in the original DF with the new series versions? ie add them to the dataframe?

**Update1**

Ideally I want to compare all the '|' separated values in systemA to those in systemB and call out where they match and where they do not.

Comment: `df['systemA_split'] = systemA`?

Comment: does that also ensure its back with the right groupBy indexx?

Comment: Ah, forget it. I didn’t notice the groupby. I don’t even understand what systemA is. Your inner code does not depend on the groupby.

Comment: I thought I needed the groupBy to keep things "grouped" by my primary key

Comment: Depending what you mean by `grouped`. If you just want to put them next together, then `sort_values` is a better choice. You may want to print `systemA` and `systemB` **without** modifying them inside the loop.

Comment: @Tony Your loop confuses me a bit.  I have a feeling that it is not doing what you intend it to do.  Take a look at this:  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups .  If you added some data and expected output, it would help us zero in on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: added more detail to help!

Comment: @Tony - per your last Update1 - you probably need that but within a `my._id` group -right?  And how do you envision the output looking like?  How do you want the matches represented?

Comment: yes thats correct - within the _id - and I'd like two one additional column added to the DF to indicate if it matched or not

Comment: @Tony So for a single value (row) of SystemA - say it is 'J|V|D|F|I' - look for J or V or D or F or I individually in the SystemB column within that _id group - which would be a number of rows that look like maybe `'C|U|K|D|Q|P', 'J|C|X|E|T|S', 'R|U|W|D|G|M'`  See if there is a match and return True/False if there is or isn't?   The above result would be True since J exists in the second row of `SystemB` and D exists in the first and third rows, etc.

Comment: yes I think thats right

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't leverage the `groupby` loop.  It builds a lookup table of `SystemB` entries per `ID` group. Then looks up the `SystemA` entries via an `apply()`:

```
df.assign(AinB_withinID=
    df.assign(tab_b=df.groupby('ID')['SystemB'].transform(lambda x: [x.str.split('|').explode().unique()]*len(x))) \
        .apply(lambda x: any([w in x['tab_b'] for w in x['SystemA'].split('|')]), axis=1)
         )

  ID SystemA SystemB  AinB_withinID
0  1     O|F     Q|Y          False
1  1   H|P|X       H           True
2  1   T|Y|I     X|U           True
3  1     Q|T     U|T           True
4  1   S|H|I     D|C           True
5  2   N|W|I     A|M           True
6  2   D|Z|K     Y|F           True
7  2   L|G|H     P|T           True
8  2   J|M|K     L|I           True
9  2   Q|Z|X     D|E          False
```